# What is the logic of server side pagination in SSRS reports

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

As I am working on SSRS reports (.rdl), I need to do pagination within reports. Usually for pagination as a asp.net developer, I add few statements in my procedure with page num and rows logic.

But as my SSRS report is also using a store procedure, do I have to do the same here? But how can i be able to handle the events then? by events i mean to say "Next page" "back page" etc. Is there any inbuilt feature for SSRS which can handle pagination. I am talking about pagination on server side as my report can be a huge and I am selecting all the records at once using procedure. could be like below:

```
Create procedure myproc
 @year int,                    
 @docid  varchar(200) 

Begin

Declare @commandtext nvarchar(max) 
set @commandtext = 'select docid, year, type,
       sum(case when statusid = 231 then 1 else 0 end) as granted,
       sum(case when statusid = 232 then 1 else 0 end) as revoked,
       sum(case when statusid = 235 then 1 else 0 end) as deleted,
       sum(case when statusid = 236 then 1 else 0 end) as others
from table1 where 1=1'

if (@year <> 0 and @year is not null)                     
set @commandtext = @commandtext + 'and year=''' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@year) + ''''  

if(@docid  is not null and @docid  <>'')                    
set @commandText = @commandtext +  'and documents in (' + @docid   + ')'    


set @commandText = @commandtext  + 'group by docid, year, type '

EXEC (@commandText);   

End
```

Answer (score 1):

Paginated Reports are standard in SSRS, you do not need to do anything special for the report to have pages, see the article below on Paginated Reports.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/pagination-in-reporting-services-report-builder-and-ssrs